# See load of separate instances on Google Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Is there a way to see CPU utilisation per configured instance ?

Currently I only see one CPU utilisation no matter if 1 or 3 instances of Google Cloud Spanner are configured.

This would be interesting to get a glimpse if our data-structure balances load evenly.

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today you can see the CPU usage of each instance by navigating to that instance's page in the [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/). Cloud Spanner doesn't separate the usage by node though, so you do only get a single figure for, say, a 3-node instance. Generally, Spanner will take care of balancing data across nodes to achieve even distribution.

Instance- and database-level utilization is also available through [Google Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/). Look for "spanner_instance" under the Metrics Explorer.